# How to independently set the font properties of each component in section titles in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, context, context-mkiv

I want to make two-line chapter titles such as this:

```
Chapter 1
Animals
```

I found instructions in this article about [titles](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles#Chapter_titles_in_new_line) at the ConTeXt wiki.

I want to adjust the font properties of each line though. With this code, I expected it would set "Chapter 1" to roman, size "c" text and set "Animals" to sans serif, size "d" text:

```
\setuplabeltext[en][chapter=Chapter~]
\define[2]\placechapter{
    \framed[align=raggedleft]{
    {\rm #1} \crlf
            {\tfd #2}
}
}
\setuphead[chapter][style={\ss\tfc}, command={\placechapter}]

\starttext
\chapter{This is the title.}

    This is some text.

\stoptext
```

Somehow though, the code is ignoring my font commands. How can I independently set the font properties of each line in a two-line section title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the style is already applied to `#1` and `#2`, so effectively you are using `\rm\ss\tfc`, so the `\ss` overrides the `\rm`. Why not simply use `textstyle` and `numberstyle` keys.

```
\setuplabeltext[en][chapter=Chapter~]

\define[2]\placechapter
    {\framed[strut=no, align=raggedleft]{#1\crlf #2}}

\setuphead[chapter][numberstyle={\rmc}, textstyle={\ssd}, command={\placechapter}]

\starttext
\chapter{This is the title.}

    This is some text.
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]